# Compare two timetables

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium

I am trying to compare 2 timetables for a college project to look for free spaces in one and then check to see events taking place in the other. For example if the student has a free slot from 4-5 on a Tuesday, My code would check to see if there are any events on at that time. I scraped the events website in order to check this. I can not seem to get the comparison part right and was looking for help in this section
this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

this is for scraping the events page

```
event_dates = {} #dictionary to store event dates and time
df = pd.read_html('https://www.dcu.ie/students/events')[0]['Event date']
event_dates.update(df)
print(event_dates)
```

this is for the timetable, checking for free slots in it

```
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window() #opens up website, and fills in information  

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://opentimetable.dcu.ie/')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")) #searchs for the select on the timetable
select.select_by_visible_text("Programmes of Study") # goes to programmes of study 

search = driver.find_element_by_id("textSearch")
search.send_keys("CASE2") #types course code into search box

checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[following-sibling::div[contains(text(), "CASE2")]]')

checkbox.click() #clicks button for course code

time.sleep(3)

html = driver.find_element_by_id("week-pdf-content").get_attribute('outerHTML')
df2 = pd.read_html(html)[0] 


#For printing free slots on timetable 
df3 = df2.set_index('Unnamed: 0') 
#print(df3.head(10).to_dict()) #for checking dataframe 
for column in df3:
    print("You have free slots at the following times:")
    print(f'{column}:{", ".join(df3[df3[column].isna()].index.drop_duplicates().to_list())}')
```

So currently I get this output from the events page :
[image: Events]

and from the timetable I get this output

[image: timetable]

So my expected output is a string saying you have a free slot on e.g tuesday at 3-4, this event is on at this time.

Any help appricated
thanks

Comment: This case study from piso might be useful https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/case_studies/calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to convert the datetime string to datetime object and then do your operations. I am using example to explain my logic. You can create a function and scale this.

Convert the string `'February 25, 09:00  - February 25, 17:00'` to 2 datetime objects (start and end).

```
import datetime as dt


time_range_string = 'February 25, 09:00  - February 25, 17:00'

# Split the string to start and end time
time_range_list = time_range_string.split("-")

# getting the start and end time string
start_time_string, end_time_string = list(map(lambda string: string.strip(), time_range_list))

start_time = dt.datetime.strptime(start_time_string, '%B %d, %H:%M')
end_time = dt.datetime.strptime(end_time_string, '%B %d, %H:%M')
```

Now you have 2 datetime objects (`start_time` and `end_time`). Since we don't have year in the string, the default year 1900 is set to the datetime objects.

Consider the string `'8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 19:00, 20:00, 21:00'`. Split these to a list.

```
time_string = '8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 19:00, 20:00, 21:00'
time_list = time_string.split(',')
```

Now combine the required date (In this case datetime(1900, 2, 25)) and time to form a new datetime object. Then we can check whether the new object is between the decided time.

```
for time_string in time_list:
    # Combine date and time
    current_date = dt.datetime.combine(dt.datetime(1900, 2, 25), dt.datetime.strptime(time_string.strip(), '%H:%M').time())
    # Checking whether full_date is between start_time and end_time
    if start_time <= current_date <= end_time:
        print(current_date)
```

This will print all times that are between the start_time and end_time. You may change the code and logic to get the required output. Create a function and then scale it to all cases.